# Manually add Phone auth user in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

is there a way I can manually create a user in Firebase with their number, without having to confirm the OTP?
with this, I can use WhatsApp API to send a random OTP on a user’s WhatsApp, and if they enter that OTP in our app I will create their user in Firebase with their entered phone number and If thats not possible, what are the alternative solutions available for authenticating the user’s phone number and creating a Firebase phone auth user?

Any suggestion in this regard would be highly appreciated.